# Automatic people counting + twittering

Tags: image-processing, twitter, computer-vision

Want to develop a system accurately counting people that go through a normal 1-2m wide door. and twitter whenever people goes in or out and tells how many people remain inside.

Now, Twitter part is easy, but people counting is difficult. There is some semi existing counting solution, but they do not quite fit my needs.

My idea/algorithm:
Should I get some infra-red camera mounting on top of my door and constantly monitoring, and divide the camera image into several grid and calculating they entering and gone?

can you give me some suggestion and starting point?

Answer (score 4):

How about having two sensors about 6 inches apart. They could be those little beam sensors (you know, the ones that chime when you walk into some shops) placed on either side of the door jam.  We'll call the sensors `S1` and `S2`

If they are triggered in the order of `S1` THEN `S2` - this means a person came in
If they are triggered in the order of `S2` THEN `S1` - this means a person left.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
|     sensor    |      door jam        |      sensor      |
-----------------------------------------------------------

        |                                        |

        |                                        |

        |                                        |

        |                                        |

        S1                                      S2     this is inside the store

        |                                        |

        |                                        |

        |                                        |

        |                                        |

-----------------------------------------------------------
|     sensor    |      door jam        |      sensor      |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: WOW awesome diagram, very good design, but i think this will only count if single-file people come in and out, but i will give it a try first.

Question, what are these sensors? (name? IR sensors?) where to buy them?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what they're called.  I also don't know of any sure fire way of doing what you need.  Do you need real time info on people in a room? Or do you need to know how many total people were in there at the end of the day?

Comment: yer i will have a look, and preferably it will tell how many people inside... like the parking lot tells how many available space inside stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to have the people filmed by a camera you can try to segment the people in the image and track them using a Particle Filter for multi-object tracking.

http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1561072&preflayout=flat

This is a paper by one of my professors. Maybe you wanna have a look at it.

If your camera is mounted and doesnt move you can use a substraction-method for segmentation of the moving people (Basically just substract two following images and all that stays where the things that move). Then do some morphological operations on it so only big parts (people) stay. Maybe even identify them by checking on rectangularity so you only keep "standing" objects.

Then use a Particle Filter to track the people in the scene automatically... And each new object would increase the counter...

If you want I could maybe send you a presentation I held a while ago (unfortunately its in German, but you can translate it)

Hope that helps...